# gmaps - several kml files set zoom

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a google map with several kml files "on it". I like to set the zoom factor dynamic, so that all kml-file contenz is shown. Is to possible to calculate boundaries of kml files, merge them and set zoom, to show all kml stuff

Comment: I think if you don't set zoom it will work as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  preserveVieport

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('your.kml', { 
  map: map,
  preserveViewport: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. set the `preserveViewport` option of each `KmlLayer` to true (to prevent the auto zoom to fit)

```
var mapLayer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: kmlUrl,
  preserveViewport: true
});
```

2. calculate the bound that is required for all the KmlLayers.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); // global
// determine the bounds for layer 1
google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer1, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
  bounds.union(mapLayer1.getDefaultViewport());
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
// include the bounds for layer 2
google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer2, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
  bounds.union(mapLayer2.getDefaultViewport());
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
// repeat for all KmlLayers you want shown
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x3z5L7qz/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(52.0, 5.1);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: location,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  //Add MapLayers
  var mapLayer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSouthern_kml.xml',
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer1, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
    bounds.union(mapLayer1.getDefaultViewport());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  mapLayer1.setMap(map);

  var mapLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSoutheastern_kml.xml',
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer2, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
    bounds.union(mapLayer2.getDefaultViewport());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  mapLayer2.setMap(map);

  var mapLayer3 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerNorthern_kml.xml',
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer3, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
    bounds.union(mapLayer3.getDefaultViewport());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  mapLayer3.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```